# Can see all computers on the networks but can't see each other

Tags: networking, file-sharing, network-bridge

I have a Windows 7 pro machine (KC-Laptop1) running a bridged network between the wireless corp.local and my wired KC_Computers_LLC.lan and I have my Ubuntu 12.04 server (KC-Server1) running on the wired.

Now KC-Server1 does get the internet and sees all the computers on corp.local except for KC-Laptop1, and KC-Laptop1 can see all the other computers on corp.local except KC-Server1. I don't know if this is an error with windows 7 pro or Ubuntu. KC-Server1 was able to see KC-Laptop1 until I just did the update for Ubuntu. but KC-Laptop1 hasn't been able to see KC-Server1 since I reloaded Ubuntu 2 days ago.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

After editing the `smb.conf`, the interfaces, the host and hostname files, and still not having any luck I restarted both machines several times and still no luck.

Finally I restarted them at the same time and they are able to see each other and the other computers on the corp.local network.